# Finding a condition on the real $a$ such that $P$ is divisible by $(x-a)^2$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $P(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1$. I have to find a condition on the real $a$ such that $P$ is divisible by $(x-a)^2$.

I tried to use [Polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) and solve a system (we need that the  remainder is the zero polynomial).

Using this theorem we have $P(x)=(x-a)^2Q(x)+q_0+q_1x$ where $(q_0,q_1)\in\Bbb{R}^2$.
So using the fact that $a$ is a root and to derive the relation we have to solve

$$
 \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}\frac{a^3}{6}+\frac{a^2}{2}+a+1=q_0+q_1a\\
    \frac{a^2}{2}+a+1=q_0
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

My problem is that the polynomial $\frac{a^2}{2}+a+1$ doesn't vanish on $\Bbb{R}$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is there any reason to think there is such an $a$? Note that $(x-a)^2$ divides a polynomial iff $P(a)=0$ and $P'(a)=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's an exercice for my exam. This why I tried to solve my system.

Comment: True, if a question says find a criterion, it is reasonable to suppose there is one! The question would be more sensible if the polynomial had a free parameter, like $c$ instead of $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Right, then we can have a positive discriminant, I will try with a free parameter to find a criterion, for progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nicer trick to determine such $a$ (if it exists) is to note that $a$ is root both of $P$ and of $P'(x)=(2(x-a)Q(x)+(x-a)^2Q'(x)$.
Now $P'(x)= \frac{x^2}2+x+1$, so $a$ must also be a root of $P(x)-P'(x)=\frac {x^3}6$, in other words, we must have $a=0$.
But obviously $0$ isn't even a root of $P$. In other words: No such $a$ exists (and that is also the result of your findings)

Comment: So the fact that the polynomial doesn't vanish it's sufficient to conclude ? Nice trick, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ (x\!-\!a)^2\mid P(x)\,\color{#C00}\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{x\!-\!a}\mid P'(x)\,\Rightarrow\, 0 = P'(a) = \frac{a^2}2+a+1,\,$ contra $\,a\in R\ \ $ **QED**

${\rm\color{#c00}{Indeed}}\,\ P = (x\!-\!a)^2 Q\,\Rightarrow\, P'\! = (\color{#0a0}{x\!-\!a})^2 Q' + 2(\color{#0a0}{x\!-\!a}) Q\,\Rightarrow\,P'(a) = 0$

**Remark** $\ $ It generalizes as follows. Let $\,P_n(x)$ be the Taylor series of $\,e^x\,$ truncated to order $\,n.$ Then $(e^x)' = e^x\,$ implies $\,P'_n(x) = P_{n-1}(x),\,$ so proceeding by induction as above we find

$\qquad\qquad (x\!-\!a)^n\mid P_{n+1} \Rightarrow\, (x\!-\!a)^{n-1}\mid P_n\,\Rightarrow\,\cdots\Rightarrow\,(x\!-\!a)^2\mid P_3,\ $ contra above

Comment: I have already accepted Hagen von Eitzen's answer but your method is really elegant and general, Thanks. +1

Comment: @Yaas My goal was to highlight how the derivative decrements multiplicity of roots, and this is "Taylor" made for that - see my Remark.

Comment: I didn't know, thanks for teaching. Then with this kind of question the 'nicer' method is to use this process ?

Comment: @BillDubuque Hi, I have one question about the second line of your answer: I think it is a short justification of the statement that comes after the first implication arrow in the first line. Is that right? In general, I don't understand when mathematicians write "indeed."